# How to add links inside a YouTube video?

Tags: youtube, video, links

I need to add links to the bottom of an YouTube video, like this Ben Stiller video here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uDN08JwNEfc

Here is a video of a guy teaching how to add little baloons to an YouTube video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u5otjHuOkVM. But he also says you cannot link outside of YouTube. The links created with this tool can only lead users to other YouTube videos.

Question: how can I add functionality similar to Ben Stiller's videos with links that lead users outside YouTube to something like a donation website?

Comment: I am thinking it has to do with that group being with the Non-Profit YouTube Program.

Comment: Hey, thanks! I am checking that.

Answer (score 2):

Linking to external websites, or a [Call-to-Action overlay](http://ytbizblog.blogspot.com/2009/06/use-call-to-action-overlays-to-drive.html), through annotations is available to partners in the Nonprofit program as well as advertisers and partners with promoted videos.

The Case Foundation show an example of this in a video, [How to Use New YouTube Annotations for Nonprofit Partners](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZK38BWy-O9E#t=1m13s).

Apart from that, you can still edit the description field to include the link to your site.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to get similar functionality using annotations;

http://www.google.com/support/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=92710

Hope this helps.

Comment: From the page you linked to: "linking is restricted to certain pages on youtube.com."

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with the type of video you describe. If you own the video, changing it to educational/tutorial for example will allow clickable links in the description